# Compiling C++ code with boost library

Tags: c++, boost, makefile

So I installed boost library as follows

```
cd /usr/local/
sudo tar --bzip2 -xf ~/Downloads/boost_1_52_0.tar.bz2
sudo ./bootsrap.sh
sudo ./b2 install
```

Now, I want to compile a code that uses boost library, and the makefile has these two lines to idenity the location of boost: (INC=.. and BOOSTLIB=..)

```
OBJS = utility.o PtDebug.o
CC = g++
INC = /usr/local/boost_1_52_0/
BOOSTLIB = /usr/local/include/boost/
CFLAGS = -Werror -g


all: my_program
```

and an example line of linking to boos in the makefile is

```
$(CC) $(FLAGS) $(OBJS)  ipMT.o -o ipmt -L$(BOOSTLIB) -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread
```

But when I try to make, it fails with this error:

```
g++  -Werror -g utility.o PtDebug.o  ratioWeightedCombIP.o -o rwcip -L/usr/local/include/boost/ -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: utility.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
//usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.57.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [misp] Error 1
```

Comment: you need to link boost_system

Comment: @Bot No, it certainly should not be migrated to Super User. This type of question is a totally valid for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Add

```
-lboost_system
```

to your link line to yield (now with indentation)

```
$(CC) $(FLAGS) $(OBJS)  ipMT.o -o ipmt \
  -L$(BOOSTLIB) -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lboost_system
```

The error message gave you a hint: No symbol `'_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'` which indicates that

1. the symbol came from the Boost System namespace, hence suggesting that you need to link this, and
2. offering a hint via a tool like `c++filt`

If you have `c++filt` you can see the mangled identifier expanded:

```
edd@max:~$ c++filt _ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv
boost::system::system_category()
edd@max:~$
```